# Need help creating a specific pointcut that utilizes a value from a method annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have the following method

```
    @AutoHandling(slot = FunctionalArea.PRE_MAIN_MENU)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String navigation(ModelMap model) {
        logger.debug("navigation");
        ...

            //First time to the Main Menu and ID-Level is ID-1 or greater
            if (!callSession.getCallFlowData().isMainMenuPlayed()
                    && callSession.getCallFlowData().getIdLevel() >= 1) {
                // Call Auto Handling                    
                logger.info("Call AutoHandling");
                autoHandlingComponent.processAutoHandling();
            }
        ...

        return forward(returnView);
    }
```

Basically what I want to do, is have a pointcut on processAutoHandling()
But in the @After, I need to use the slot() for @AutoHandling

I tried this, but it does not get called

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.processAutoHandling())")
public void processAutoHandleCall() {
    logger.debug("processAutoHandleCall");
}

@Around("processAutoHandleCall() &&" +
        "@annotation(autoHandling) &&" +
        "target(bean) "
)
public Object processAutoHandlingCall(ProceedingJoinPoint jp,
                                      AutoHandling autoHandling,
                                      Object bean)
        throws Throwable {
         ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the wormhole design pattern for this. I am illustrating using AspectJ byte-code based approach and syntax, but you should be able to get the same effect using an explicit ThreadLocal if you are using Spring's proxy-based AOP.

```
pointcut navigation(AutoHandling handling) : execution(* navigation(..)) 
                                             && @annotation(handling);

// Collect whatever other context you need
pointcut processAutoHandleCall() : execution(* *.processAutoHandling());

pointcut wormhole(AutoHandling handling) : processAutoHandleCall() 
                                           && cflow(navigation(handling));

after(AutoHandling handling) : wormhole(hanlding) {
   ... you advice code
   ... access the slot using handling.slot()
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer as usual (+1). @Mick read his book [AspectJ in Action, 2nd ed](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/) for more info about the wormhole pattern

Answer (score 0):

a) It can't work, you are trying to match two different things:

```
@Around("processAutoHandleCall() &&" +
        "@annotation(autoHandling) &&" +
        "target(bean) "
)
```

`processHandleCall()` matches the inner method execution `autoHandlingComponent.processAutoHandling()` while `@annotation(autoHandling)` matches the outer method execution `navigation(ModelMap model)`

b) since you are obviously trying to advise a Controller, there are a few caveats:

- if you use `proxy-target-class=true` everything should work as is, just make sure you don't have any final methods
- if you don't, all your controller methods must be backed by an interface and the `@RequestMapping` etc annotations must be on the interface, not the implementing class as described in [this section of the Spring MVC reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)

Comment: That can I add the Annotation at the actual Call?

Comment: @Mick You can't annotate a method call, but you could annotate the processAutoHandling() method.

Comment: I have that, but my issue now is I need to actually redirect the return value for the controller, but by just using processAutoHandling() I cannot for a return value for NavigationController can I?