# Need help creating a specific pointcut inside of a method

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, aop

I started with an original question on
[Need help creating a specific pointcut that utilizes a value from a method annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759803/need-help-creating-a-specific-pointcut-that-utilizes-a-value-from-a-method-annota)

I decided I wanted to ask another question to change the approach I was taking.
I have a method (*navigation*), that has a call inside of that method to another method which I would like to have @Around advice.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String navigation(ModelMap model) {
    ...        
            // Call Auto Handling
            logger.info("Call AutoHandling");
            this.processAutoHandling(callSession, FunctionalArea.PRE_MAIN_MENU);
        }
        ...

    return forward(returnView);
}
```

Is this possible as I cannot seem to get this to work if the method is inside of the same class.

This work if it was not on the object itself:

```
@Around("execution(* *.processAutoHandling(..)) &&" +
        "args(callSession, functionalArea) && " +
        "args(functionalArea) && " +
        "target(bean)"
)
public Object processAutoHandlingCall2(ProceedingJoinPoint jp,
                                      CallSession callSession,
                                      FunctionalArea functionalArea,
                                      Object bean)
        throws Throwable {
    logger.debug("processAutoHandleCall");
    return jp.proceed();
}
```

With this call in my controller:

```
autoHandlingComponent.processAutoHandling(callSession, FunctionalArea.PRE_MAIN_MENU);
```

instead of

```
this.processAutoHandling(callSession, FunctionalArea.PRE_MAIN_MENU);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using Spring's proxy-based AOP. If so, this is a known limitation. See [Understanding AOP Proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) from Spring documentation for more details. You have two ways to solve this issue:

1. Use the `AopContext.currentProxy()` approach outlined in the documentation. I will discourage this approach, since your code will now be tied to Spring AOP quite explicitly.
2. Use AspectJ's byte-code weaving. Since there is no proxy involved with it, you won't have the issue with 'this' pointing to original object and proxy is transparently available only to external objects.